# Is it safe to install cyogenMod on my rooted, bricked , then unrooted Samsung Captivate

Tags: cyanogenmod, installation, samsung-captivate

My Samsung captivate was running the latest version of Android available to it which is 2.3.5 Gingerbread.

I rooted it by installing ClockworkMod Recovery, (flashing zImage using heimdall on Ubuntu), I then installed CyanogenMod 10. It worked up until the point I went and tried to restore the data or db data(can't remember) part of the backup I made in CWM. This broke the ROM I had to revert to a stock ROM I found.

Firmware version: `2.1-update1`

Baseband Version: `I897ucjf6`

I then tried to restore the custom ROM to no avail. The CWM recovery log said something to the extent of I can't re partition the device or mount the device due to a bad sector. The long and short it did not work.

When I start the phone normally, it does not boot. When I hold 2 vol keys the screen looks as if a VGA cable is not connected properly - everything is colorful, but distorted (no text is recognizable).

Is there a way to get an official (or official-ish) version of Android 4.1 on my phone, preferably using Odin 100% of the time so I am not having to boot into recovery and apply update from zip (Although I can do this if needs be).

Should I use Kies Mini to update to Gingerbread and try again?

Should I just forget about my Android 4.1 dream?

I followed [this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Captivate%3a_Full_Update_Guide) guide the first time I rooted the phone.
I downloaded CyanogenMod 10 from their seemingly official website under the Samsung Captivate section.